# Excepción al crear objeto Workbook con Spire

Tags: excel, pdf, reflection, spire

Quiero crear un pdf desde un archivo Excel, código:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile(@"D:\excels\Report.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2016);
workbook.SaveToFile(@"D:\excels\" + name + ".pdf", Spire.Xls.FileFormat.PDF);
```

me da la siguiente excepción en la primera linea al instanciar workbook:

[image]

reinstale la librería , puse copia local en propiedades de la referencia y sigue pasando , ¿alguna idea de porque falla?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de limpiar dependencias , paquetes, desinstalar e instalar con nuget solo el Spire.XLS que era el que necesitaba.. funcionó. Algo quedo en conflicto al instalar diferentes paquetes antes..